# Increase PHP-FPM's max upload file size

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I've increased params values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 12M
```

And `php --ini` command in console shows me:

```
post_max_size => 12M => 12M
upload_max_filesize => 10M => 10M
```

But anyways, when I'm trying to send file > 1mb I get err. In nginx logs I see:

```
2017/06/03 12:06:40 [error] 16254#16254: *7 client intended to send too large body: 1778665 bytes
```

`fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 10M \n post_max_size=12M"` in nginx conf doesn't help too.

So, how can I increase max upload file size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nginx` have its own option called `client_max_body_size` that can be defined for `http`, `server` and `location` context. Check whether that options is set to non-zero value or not. You can set it to zero to disable body size checkout and then only PHP settings become actual.

Comment: Looks like `client_max_body_size 0;` in the `server` section of nginx config did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to check the active .ini settings via PHP's `phpinfo()` function from a script that you are executing via PHP-FPM. Running `php --ini` shows settings that apply to the command line PHP, which might be different from PHP-FPM.

To change PHP-FPM php.ini values, you need to edit the pool configuration file, and add

```
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 12M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 10M
```

These will change the INI settings applied to the PHP-FPM pool you are running.

Alternatively you can look up the `php.ini` file for your PHP-FPM setup and change the setting over there.

Comment: This changes in pool configuration file didn't help .

Comment: Did you restart PHP-FPM after changes?

Comment: Yep, I've restarted fpm and nginx.

Comment: I was banging my head until I realised I'd used `php_admin_value[upload_max_size] = 10M` ...